# Laravel sync multiple additional dynamic values

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, synchronization, pivot

I have a form where I submit multiple values. It's a dynamic form where the fields differ each time, but onlt the quantity of the fields, not the fields itself. I am using the following to insert all data in the pivot table, however I hardly think this is a good way of going about this. Is there a good way of accomplishing this without using a foreach perhaps? Right now for only 3 `exercises` I'm doing 12 queries? xD

The pivot table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `exercise_training` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `exercise_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `training_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `exercise_set` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `exercise_repeat` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `exercise_weight` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `exercise_time` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
)
```

And here is the code:

```
    $checkedSets = $request['exercise_sets']; // Array of `set` values where the `key` is the `exercise_id`
    $checkedRepeats = $request['exercise_repeats'];// Array of `repeat` values where the `key` is the `exercise_id`
    $checkedWeights = $request['exercise_weights'];// Array of `weight` values where the `key` is the `exercise_id`
    $checkedTimes = $request['exercise_times'];// Array of `time` values where the `key` is the `exercise_id`

    foreach($checkedSets as $key => $value)
    {
        $training->exercises()->syncWithoutDetaching([$key => ['exercise_set' => $value]]);
    }

    foreach($checkedRepeats as $key => $value)
    {
        $training->exercises()->syncWithoutDetaching([$key => ['exercise_repeat' => $value]]);
    }

    foreach($checkedWeights as $key => $value)
    {
        $training->exercises()->syncWithoutDetaching([$key => ['exercise_weight' => $value]]);
    }

    foreach($checkedTimes as $key => $value)
    {
        $training->exercises()->syncWithoutDetaching([$key => ['exercise_time' => $value]]);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

From [laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships)

```
You may also pass additional intermediate table values with the IDs:

$user->roles()->sync([1 => ['expires' => true], 2, 3]);
```

Comment: Thanks, I did try that already but without success, but it could be I was doing it wrong. I haven't looked into this for a while, I will check it out again later :)